# Oracle repository

Tags: sql, git, oracle, version-control, repository

I have repository connected with the integrated source control in oracle. I did full export without any data from tables of my database as separate directories and it looks fine. The problem is that every time I want to change something I have export the stored procedure or table sql code and then to upload it in the repository, which is hard because at the end of the day I'm not sure about how many changes I did and I can forgot some of them. Full export without data could have been the solution but I don't have the time to wait for export 20-25 minutes at the end of every day. Is there any way to just export the changes which are made at the current day or made after the last export. Or maybe directly export the sql code on each compilation inside oracle management studio? The database is not on my computer its located in a server which I'm connected to.

[here is how my git folder looks like in separate folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5BR.png)

Answer (score 2):

You need to work the other way around. To change a package for example, open the corresponding source code file from your Git repository in your development tool (SQL Developer, PL/SQL Developer etc), make your changes, test, save the file, check in with ticket number and comment. As a rule you should not edit stored code directly in the database. (PL/SQL Developer has a checkbox "Allow editing of database source", which I generally leave unchecked. Probably other tools have something similar.)